# r read files and iterate function returning +

Tags: r, function, matrix, arguments

## My scenario

I have a series of files `tfiles`, each of them containing a two column matrix that I pass into a function named `ComputeStepSize`.

This `ComputeStepSize` function measures the difference between each of the column descending values in each of the `tfiles` (using an **ith index" +1 iteration scheme**).

So far I've done the following:

**1)** I have made a list of the files using the system command to be able to read them and store them in `individualmatrices`:

```
individualmatrices1<-system("ls /Users/otherdirectory/rpractice/tfiles*", intern=TRUE)
```

**2)** I have a `read` function that reads the `individualmatrices` list created previously:

```
read <- function(tfile) {
  a <- read.table(tfile, sep="\t", header=TRUE)
  return(a)
}
```

**3)** `tlist` function fills an empty array with the content returned by the previous `read` function:

```
tlist<-vector("list", 100)
  for (i in 1:length(individualmatrices1)){
    val <- read(individualmatrices1[i])
    tlist[[i]]<-val
  }
```

**4)** And finally I compute the step size (**I'm not sure if the argument in the brackets of "function" should be my `tfiles` or my `tlist`...**):

```
ComputeStepSize<-function(tfiles){
  for(i in 1:length(tlist)){
    deltastep1<-(tlist[i+1,2]-tlist[i,2])/(tlist[i+1,1]-tlist[i,1])
    print(deltastep1)
  }
}
```

### The issue

Unfortunately when I run the command it returns a series of `+` signs that keep reappearing each time I press `Enter`... so I have to press `Escape` to be able to type commands again.

Then I type `ComputeStepSize(tfiles)` and get the following *error* returned:

> 'Error: could not find function "ComputeStepSize"'.

Which is not very informative to me...

### My questions

1. Can anyone see if there is something wrong with the way that I have read my files that could perturb the final function's result?
2. Is there anything wrong with the `ComputeStepSize` function? I have thoroughly checked code syntax regarding the actual strategy that I'm employing to compute the individual step sizes... maybe with the arguments that I'm passing into this function?

Comment: thank you for those useful edits

Comment: You are welcome, I hope I didn't miss anything and the edition shows what you actually pretended to be asking.

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the values in the `read`- and `tlist`-objects. Furthermore you do not actually show what command is resulting in the "+" signs, which is an indication of a mismatched parenthesis or brace. The `ComputeStepSize` function is only going to give you the last value in that loop. You need to start at the beginning and report on what the results of those assignments in 1,2,and 3 are.

Comment: And shouldn't it be `ComputeStepSize(tlist)`? ... which raises the question whether that function is designed to handle lists? It doesn't appear to be so designed.

Comment: Thank you 42. the content of tlist prints all of the desired matrices. However, tlist[i] only prints the last matrix...
The for loop inside ComputeSizeStep:
                    
                    > for(i in 1:length(trajectorieslist)){
                    +     deltastep1<-(tlist[i+1,2]-tlist[i,2])/(tlist[i+1,1]-tlist[i,1])
                    + }
                    Error in tlist[i + 1, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions

So i tried iterating by column with "for(i in dim(trajectories list)[2])" but that returned the same error....

Comment: Hi there I have since changed the argument of the function to the list that contains the files input and I put the for loop that defines that list inside of the command parameters... but the command still doesn't recognise the list? I'm really lost here